# How can I get a datatemplate to fill uniform grid cell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uniformgrid

Here is my xaml. I need the red grid to fill the entire cell.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Atelis.Tcc.Client.CheckList_TileView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding Model}">
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCheck}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns=" 3 "/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenSelectedCheck, ElementName=TileView}"/>
                </Grid.InputBindings>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CheckRoot.CheckNum}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CheckRoot.CheckDate}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My goal is to allow the user to click anywhere in the cell to perform the InputBinding command. So if there is another way to accomplish that goal, that will also suffice as an answer.

[image]

Comment: what is the issue here? to fill uniform grid or to invoke the command?

Comment: The issue is to fill the grid.

Comment: by looking at the code, it looks like the template should be filling the cell with red color. perhaps you can post a image showing the issue.

Comment: @PriceJones problem is with command or display? For starters `ListBoxItem` will handle left mouse click and this `ElementName` binding won't work in your `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I got you correct then it looks like your cells are not fully stretched in the listbox

so setting `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` &  `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` will do the trick

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCheck}" >
```

**Alternative approach**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCheck}" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
```

this approach will also help you remove the selected background (usually blue) if you may want to remove that too

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I needed. I both love and hate wpf. It is very flexible, so I love wpf. But I can't keep up with its many quirks. Thanks.